# Inclusion of additional characters in Autopair.

Tags: emacs, elisp

Autopair is not working for { and '.
Is there any code that needs to added?

Answer (score 2):

Autopair works by analysing the [syntax table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table) for the particular major mode you're in. There are entries there for **open delimiter**, **close delimiter** and **paired delimiters**(marked with a **(**, **)** and **$** symbols). You have to modify the syntax table to alter autopair's behaviour.

This would make the { and } delimiters matching each other:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?{ "(}")
(modify-syntax-entry ?} "){")
```

Btw, Emacs 24.1 includes a built-in mode called `electric-pair-mode` that's fairly similar to autopair-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the major mode you're using.  But if you want to add specific pairs additionally to the ones specified by your major-mode, there is a variable for it.  Check `M-x customize-group RET autopair RET`.